# Add namespace attribute to xml node in php

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, domdocument

Following is the node I am trying to create in my XML -

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no" ?>
<manifest identifier="com.scorm.golfsamples.contentpackaging.multioscosinglefile.20043rd"
          version="1"
          xmlns="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imscp_v1p1"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xmlns:adlcp="http://www.adlnet.org/xsd/adlcp_v1p3"
          xmlns:adlseq="http://www.adlnet.org/xsd/adlseq_v1p3"
          xmlns:adlnav="http://www.adlnet.org/xsd/adlnav_v1p3"
          xmlns:imsss="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imsss"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imscp_v1p1 imscp_v1p1.xsd
                              http://www.adlnet.org/xsd/adlcp_v1p3 adlcp_v1p3.xsd
                              http://www.adlnet.org/xsd/adlseq_v1p3 adlseq_v1p3.xsd
                              http://www.adlnet.org/xsd/adlnav_v1p3 adlnav_v1p3.xsd
                              http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imsss imsss_v1p0.xsd">
```

Code is working fine for `identifier` and `version` attribute but unable to generate it with namespace like `xmlns="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imscp_v1p1"`

Tried this code from [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createattributens.php) but unable to make it :(

```
$doc = new DOMDocument( '1.0' );
$doc->loadXML( $source );

// (1) We just create a "namespace'd" attribute without appending it to any element.
$attr_ns = $doc->createAttributeNS( '{namespace_uri_here}', 'example:attr' );

print $doc->saveXML() . "\n";
```

Codepad Link - http://codepad.org/uLJc4hpP

Full code -

```
   //creating an XML document
    $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
    $dom->xmlStandalone = false;

    //create element manifest
    $manfiestNode = $dom->createElement('manifest',"");

    //create attribute identifier
    $manfiestNodeAttr = $dom->createAttribute('identifier');

    //value for the manifest node identifier value
    $date = new DateTime();
    $manfiestNodeAttr->value = 'course_'.date_format($date,'U');

    //append attribute to the manifest element
    $manfiestNode->appendChild($manfiestNodeAttr);

    //create attribute with an associated namespace
    $nodeAttr = $manfiestNode->createAttributeNS('{namespace_uri_here}', 'example:attr');

    //append namespace to the manifest element
    $nodeAttr->appendChild($manfiestNode);

    //append manifest element to the document
    $dom->appendChild($manfiestNode);

    var_dump($dom->saveXML());
```

Let me know what I am conceptually doing wrong and how could I make it working.

I tried by changing `$manfiestNode` to `$dom` in line 20[codepad link] but still no luck :(.

Error-

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method DOMElement::createAttributeNS()
>   on line 20

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try with `createAttribute` like following

```
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0','UTF-8'); 

// root manifest
$root = $dom->appendChild($dom->createElement('manifest')); 

// identifier   
$date = new DateTime();
$manfiestNodeAttr_value = 'course_'.date_format($date,'U');

$root->appendChild($dom->createAttribute('identifier'))->appendChild($dom->createTextNode($manfiestNodeAttr_value)); 

// version
$version = 1;

$root->appendChild($dom->createAttribute('version'))->appendChild($dom->createTextNode($version)); 

// xmlns:xsi
$root->appendChild($dom->createAttribute('xmlns:xsi'))->appendChild($dom->createTextNode("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"));

print_r($dom->saveXML());
```

**Demo Codepad:** http://codepad.org/zgug0Gl3

Comment: my question is about generating `xmlns:xsi` these type of attributes, version and identifier is sucessfully created from above code

Comment: @swapnesh But you can create `xmlns` with `createAttribute`?

Comment: yeah i tried that way `$dom->createAttribute('xmlns:xsi')` and it works :) only thing is is it really a clean way of generating like this..let me know if you have some thoughts on it +1 :)

Comment: I do not know very well about `DOMDocument`. I just googled and looked aroud php.net and want to help you. Updated codes with sample `xmlns:xsi` create attribute like yours.

Comment: ohh issue with that...if I add for a xml output `header('Content-type: application/xml');` then it is not showing the `xmlns:xsi` however it is showing in a string

Comment: I added too and showing well xml format. What exactly the issue?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36768/discussion-between-swapnesh-and-bora)